# How to get rid of the black line?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, scene

How to get rid of the black line?

I don't want to delete the scene but I need to get rid of the viewport line, its not an overlay I tried to toggle it off, it also cannot be clicked on

[image]

link to file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZrleXoLNXuz6vINENgeDZrZpjcgWAiDJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like a bugged view area. If you right-click the top of this "separator line" you get the area context menu. Unfortunately, there is no entry to join or close the area. To get rid of it, you could delete the *Layout* workspace and re-create it with the [+] button at the top right, then move the new workspace to the front with the context menu.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have broken the interface somehow. You can make this.

1. File → New → General
2. File → Open
3. In open dialog, select file with broken UI and uncheck "Load UI"

[image]

4. File will load with default interface.

Comment: thanks it appears to work (load without UI), I got it broken from download already

Comment: @semperpi 
Hello and welcome. This site is not a regular forum.  Please don't reply "Thanks" as an answer or comment, instead [upvote the post that helped you](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). If you feel it completely solved your issue consider [marking it as accepted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).